# How to swap external SD card with intenal one on rooted Ematic EGS102 tablet?

Tags: external-sd, mount, internal-sd

Today I rooted my Chinese tablet (Ematic EGS102), and opened its `vold.fstab` but I can't find the line that points to the internal memory. This is what I found:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: vold.fstab]

All I know is:

- The line mentioning "`dev_mount flash`" is the nand flash.
- Next line is for the external SD and the another next one  is for USB.

So which line should be used to swap external_sd with?

My internal storage has only 500 MB capacity so swapping would be really useful. I tried moving apps to SD card but it moves them to nand flash and the data keeps downloading in the internal, so storage runs out and apps don't work.

[image: IMG: storage]

Help would be greatly appreciated.